# C# - Unable to Access Methods Included in C++/CLI .dll

Tags: c#, c++, function, dll, global

I have two C++/CLI DLLs that I am trying to use with C#. I am using VS10 and have made sure that the DLLs are appropriately included in the "References" folder.

So, the first DLL works great. It contains classes, so the C# application can access the functions within the classes by 1) creating an instance of a class found in the DLL, then 2) calling the function "normally." (e.g. `instanceOfClass.method1();`).

**The second DLL does not work.** In the second DLL, all functions are at a global scope. No namespace scopes or classes. I am running into issues here, because when I try to access one of these functions in the C# application, I get an error: `The name 'fxn' does not exist in the current context.` I have tried all of the following possible ways of addressing the function:

```
namespace myDLL {           // Tried with and without namespace declaration
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            fxnInitialize();
            myDLL.fxnInitialize();
            myDLL->fxnInitialize();    
        }
    }
}
```

All of the other questions I have found regarding this issue have been with C++ DLLs with classes. *My* issue is: **Is it possible to reference methods in DLLs that *don't* belong to a class?**

- If it is possible, what am I doing wrong? I suspect I might be limiting the namespace (or some scope) in my C# application that is not allowing it see the contents of the DLL
- If it is not possible, why can't C# not use "class-less" DLLs? Is there a way to get around this, or another way to avoid using classes in the library (for easiest accessibility)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If it is not possible, why can't C# not use "class-less" DLLs?

Because the CLR does not support it, methods must always be a member of a class.  That's an impedance mismatch with C++'s support for free functions.  The C++/CLI compiler solves it by moving them into a class anyway.  It's name is `<Module>` and it is not accessible outside of the assembly.  Like an *internal* class in C#.  In effect making the functions inaccessible as well.

Solving it is simple, add them to a ref class.  You can declare them *static*.

Comment: This explanation is very informative. I figured that something like this might be the case, but I did not know how to put it into words. Thanks

Comment: Update: Additionally, I found this reference on MSDN that says: "If you are progamming in Visaul Basic or C#, you must declare DLL functions within a class or Visual Basic module." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/khbsw73t(v=vs.100).aspx